# Searching set of keywords in same order by using regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

Let say there are lines like the following

```
AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF
BBB CCC EEE DDD FFF
HHH XXX TTT SSS PPP QQQ
...
```

And I want to search for AAA CCC in the same order. So the expected outcome would be

```
AAA CCC
CCC
...
```

Is there a one-line regex to produce these?

Comment: Perhaps. What have you tried?

Comment: Why would `CCC` match `AAA` `CCC` ? Why does your title say "random order" and your question say "same order" ?

Comment: And ... are you asking how to search for two separate targets, or a continguous pair of targets? Given your sample output `grep -o 'AAA|CCC' file` might work for two separate targets. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/AAA\/BBB/{s/\(AAA \?\)\|\(CCC\).*\|./\1\2/g;s/ $//;p}' file
```

This solution suggested by **revo** maintains the order of the target strings, see below for the solution that does not and its description that this ameliorated solution is based on.

```
sed -n '/AAA\|BBB/!b;s/\(AAA \?\|CCC \?\)\|./\1/g;s/ $//;p' file
```

Set the `-n` option on to selectively print the pattern space. If the current line does not contain the target string, effectively do nothing and replace it with the next line. Otherwise, replace a target (followed by zero or one space) by its self or remove the next character in the pattern space globally. Finally remove any trailing space and print the pattern space. Thanks to **revo** for the original idea.

N.B. This is not a one line regexp,

```
grep -o 'AAA\|CCC' file
```

Will extract the target string from each line but will print multiple times per line if there is more than one match per line, as seen by using the `-n` option:

```
grep -no 'AAA\|CCC'  file
```

If the file(s) are large, a combination of grep and sed might be more efficient:

```
grep -hnow 'AAA\|CCC' file |
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^(([^:]*:).*)\n\2/\1 /;ta;s/^[^:]*://;P;D'
```

Comment: Can we shorten that sed cmd? `sed -r 's/(AAA *)|(CCC).*|./\1\2/g; /^$/d;'`

Comment: @revo thanks, however that regexp does not quite work (reverse the targets you will see what I mean). Using the same idea though does, see edit.

Comment: I think it is doing well in a reverse order. `CCC AAA` should return `CCC` because as I can read from OP there is an *order* which means whatever comes after `CCC` should be ignored otherwise there is no *order*. OP may clarify on this.

Comment: Otherwise it is like doing this `sed -r 's/(AAA *|CCC *)|./\1/g; s/ *$//; /^$/d;'`

Comment: @revo you are right all the time. I really should read the question all the way through.

Comment: I may be wrong but is there any difference between the last I proposed and your last edit?

Comment: @revo I am a snail when it comes to editing the answer and was still doing so whilst your comment was posted.